# Showing that $(ab,d^2)=1$ where $d=(m,n)$ and $m=ad$ and $n=bd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $d=(m,n)$ then $m=ad$ and $n=bd$. How can I show that $(ab,d^2)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Take $a=2$, $b=3$, $d=6$. Then $m=12$, $n=18$, so that $(n,m)=6=d$, yet $(ab,d^2)=6\neq 1$.

I hope this demonstrates the importance of trying small values first before proving something. Not only does it give you feel for the problem, potential proofs, and in some cases solutions; it also prevents you from trying to solve theorems that aren't even true.

Comment: I guess that it must be some typo in my book but that is too bad because as a beginner, I thought that it is true and spent more than three hours trying to prove it while it is not true.

Comment: Then again; with every single problem you have, try some small values. Especially number theory. Perhaps that's what the book is trying to teach you, and you learned it the hard way.